# MacOS get directory symlink'd file is located in

Tags: bash, macos-sierra

Is it possible to get the directory a symlink'd file is located in.  For example:

File A in directory X is a symlink of file B in directory Y.  I want the path to directory Y while running scripts involving file A.

Edit: utilizing readlink doesn't work same way in MacOS as it does in other Unix projects.  Would prefer to not need to install additional tools.

Comment: What's wrong with `dirname "$(readline "X/A")"`?

Comment: Being a somewhat bash noob how would that line actually look in a bash script?

Comment: Also did you mean `readlink`?

Comment: I did; I might blame autocorrect, but I made the same typo when I was testing `readlink`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on chepner's comments was able to get this to work:

```
path=`dirname "$(readlink "$BASH_SOURCE")"`
```